# How to deactivate the caching of gradle properties?

Tags: gradle, caching

Depending on the user, a different set of properties are load from a file.

```
ext.userProps = new Properties(defaults.userProperties)
file("env/configurations/user_${userName}.properties").withInputStream { userProps.load(it) }
```

1. User runs the first build -> everything works fine
2. User changes a property in the file
3. Runs the build again -> **gradle still uses the old properties**

Workaround: running *gradlew clean* after every change to a properties file. Then it works as expected.

How can I tell gradle directly, to **not cache** the loaded properties?

---

Edit:
The properties are then used to make string replacements in configuration files.

```
ext.dbconfig = ""
ext.siteProps = new Properties(defaults.siteProperties)
file("env/configurations/site_${siteName}.properties").withInputStream { siteProps.load(it) }

ext.userProps = new Properties(defaults.userProperties)
file("env/configurations/user_${userName}.properties").withInputStream { userProps.load(it) }

ext.tokens = [
        // WEB-INF/web.xml
        smtpHostName              : "${siteProps.'mail.smtp.host'}".toString(),
        smtpPassword              : "${siteProps.'mail.smtp.password'}".toString(),
        hibernateSchemaCreation   : "${userProps.'hibernate.schema.creation'}".toString(),
        documentExportMode        : "${userProps.'document.exportMode'}".toString(),
        multipartConfigLocation   : "${siteProps.'multipartConfigLocation'}".toString(),

        // META-INF/context.xml">
        'hibernate.datasource.url': "${userProps.'hibernate.datasource.url'}".toString(),
        'hibernate.dialect' : "${userProps.'hibernate.dialect'}".toString(),
        'hibernate.connection.username' : "${userProps.'hibernate.connection.username'}".toString(),
        'hibernate.connection.password' : "${userProps.'hibernate.connection.password'}".toString(),
        'hibernate.connection.driver.class': "${userProps.'hibernate.connection.driver.class'}".toString(),
]
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide more context? It would be beneficial to see the task that's being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using external data to impact the execution result of some tasks, without letting Gradle know. This breaks the up-to-date checking.

Have a look at the [documentation on up-to-date checking](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks) and in particular the [Runtime API](https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api) which enables you to tell existing Gradle tasks that another input needs to be considered.

Once all inputs are declared properly, changing these properties file will cause Gradle to re-execute the relevant tasks.

So given what you indicated, you most likely want to enhance the `processResource` task, which will then properly be run whenever a properties file change. That will in cause change the produced jar, which will cause tests to re-run, etc ...